# Show that if $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and $|f(z)|$ is constant in $D$, then the function $f(z)$ is constant in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that if $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and $|f(z)|$ is constant in $D$, then the function $f(z)$  is constant in $D$.

Here is what I try so far.

So we are given that $|f(z)|$ is constant in $D$, so that means $|f(z)|^2 = u^2 + v^2$ is also constant.  If either $u = 0$, or $v = 0$, then $f(z)$ is constant.

$$\frac{\partial|f(z)|^2}{\partial x} = 2u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial|f(z)|^2}{\partial y} = 2u \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + 2v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -2u \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + 2v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0 $$

So what do I do to finish this proof? Would I have to use the Cauchy Riemann equation?

Comment: do you know the open mapping theorem?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $c\ne 0$ is such that
\begin{align*}
|f(z)|&=c\\
|f(z)|^{2}&=c^{2}\\
f(z)\overline{f(z)}&=c^{2}\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}f(z)\overline{f(z)}&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\overline{f(z)}+f(z)\cdot\overline{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}}&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\overline{f(z)}&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}&=0,
\end{align*}
so $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Using $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$ and $v_y$ for the partial derivatives, you have
\begin{cases}
uu_x+vv_x=0 \\[4px]
uu_y+vv_y=0
\end{cases}
By C-R, $v_y=u_x$ and $v_x=-u_y$, so you have
\begin{cases}
uu_x-vu_y=0 \\[4px]
vu_x+uu_y=0
\end{cases}
Multiply the first equation by $u$, the second by $v$ and sum:
$$
(u^2+v^2)u_x=0
$$
If $f$ is not the constant zero, the set where $u^2+v^2=0$ has no limit point. Thus its complement, where $u_x=0$, is dense in $D$. Hence $u_x=0$. Similarly, $u_y=0$, $v_x=0$ and $v_y=0$.

Comment: quick question how you get $uu_x + vv_x = 0$ and $uu_y + vv_y = 0$?

Comment: @EM4 Do the partial derivatives of $u^2+v^2=0$: for $x$ you get $2uu_x+2vv_x=0$

Comment: yes yes yes, I figured this out after. 

my last question why $u^2 + v^2 = 0$ has no limit point because..? is it if $f$ isn't constant?

Comment: @EM4 A limit point of this set would be a limit point of the zeros of $f$ and this would imply $f$ is constant (because it's analytic to begin with). In the previous comment it should have been $u^2+v^2=c$ (constant).

Comment: I believe you did a mistake, it should be  $u^2 + v^2 \neq 0$

Comment: @EM4 Where? The set where $u^2+v^2=0$ has no limit point, so the set where $u^2+v^2\ne0$ is dense; thus $u_x$ is zero on a dense set and, being continuous, is zero everywhere.

Comment: Sir, the function $f(z) =e^{iz}$ is analytic in any domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, $|f(z) |= 1$ for all $z\in D$. But $f(z) $ is not constant in $D$

Comment: @GeneralMathematics $f(-i)=e^{-i^2}=e$. Actually, $|e^{iz}|=1$ if and only is $z$ is real.