# $|f(z)|$ is constant but $f(z)$ is not constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

According to this post [Show that if $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and $|f(z)|$ is constant in $D$, then the function $f(z)$ is constant in $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651031/1206247)
We have,

> If $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and $|f(z)|$ is constant in $D$ then the function $f(z)$ is constant in $D$.

**But**, If I consider the function $f(z) =e^{iz}$ then clearly $f$ is analytic on any domain $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, $|f(z) |=1$ for all $z\in D$ But, $f(z) =e^{iz}$ is **Not** constant in $D$.

I think, I made some mistake. But I am not getting where! Please help me.

Comment: What makes you think that $|e^{iz}|=1$ for all $z$? What is $|e^{(i)(i)}|$?

Comment: @geetha290krm , I think $|e^{iz}|=\sqrt{cos^2(z) +sin^2(z)} =1$ for $z\in D$. We may take $D$ be unit disk

Comment: Did you read my coment fully?

Comment: @geetha290krm, yep.$ |e^{(i)(i)}|=|e^{i^2}|=|e^{-1}|=\frac{1}{e}$. So $|e^{iz}|=|cosz +isinz|≠1$? When this equal to $1$? and What if we consider $D$ to be domain on which this value equals to $1$?

Comment: $|e^{i\cdot (-i)}| = e > 1$.

Comment: It is a serious mistake to think that whatever is true for real number is also true for complex numbers.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic and non constant, it is an open map.

Comment: @copper.hat sir, so isn't there is domain on which the value of $|e^{iz}|$ is $1$?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Assuming that a domain is open, then no.

Comment: @copper.hat sir, So there is no open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ on which $|e^{iz}|=1$ holds?

Comment: $|e^{iz}|=1$ if and only if $z$ is real and the real line has no interior points. .

Comment: @GeneralMathematics You should stop calling people "sir". Women also do Mathematics. How do you know the gender of the other users?

Comment: @jjagmath by seeing their profile and username. Further, If someone is helping us, then at least we should give them respect No matter what's their age and gender.

Comment: @geetha290krm mam, your comments also helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **But**, If I consider the function $f(z) =e^{iz}$ then clearly $f$ is analytic on any domain $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$.

Correct.

> Moreover, $|f(z) |=1$ for all $z\in D$

No. $|f(z)|=1$ if and only if $z\in\mathbb{R}$. But for example $f(i)=e^{-1}$ and so $|f(i)|\neq 1$.

When we are dealing with complex analysis, the term "domain" almost always means at least open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. And therefore $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is impossible, since $\mathbb{R}$ has empty interior in $\mathbb{C}$.

And this implies that $|f(z)|=1$ for all $z\in D$ is also impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $z=x+iy$, then $f(z)=e^{iz}=e^{ix}e^{-y}=e^{-y}(\cos{x}+i \sin{x})$, so $|f|$ is not constant when $y$ increases.
You may ignore that $z\in \mathbb{C}$,  not a real variable.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ entire and $\mid f(z)\mid=c\implies f$ is bounded.   Then by Liouville's theorem $f$ is constant.

It's interesting to note that, in the link you provided,  we find that this is also true when $f$ is only analytic on a domain $D\subset \Bbb C.$